# convert an asp.net webpage to pdf With Ajax Tab Container

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, pdf

I am creating an website which have too much data import and exports,users all data are displayed in ajax tab container,my problem is that when i am try to export those data in PDF it displays following error:

```
Script control 'TabPanel1' is not a registered script control. Script controls must be registered using RegisterScriptControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors().
```

Parameter name: scriptControl

i am using `iTextSharp` dll library for Exports all data which contain in tab panels in pdf
on code side i declare all name spaces :

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

and set an code for export page into pdf :

```
 protected void pdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        this.Page.RenderControl(hw);

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```

But it displays above error, can anyone can help me:

Answer (score 0):

Set the registerWithScriptManager property of your control to false
(registerWithScriptManager="false")

you will probably have to type it in, there usually isn't a spot for it in the properties pane.